# Three.js postprocess antialiasing on texture RT

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to avoid no antialiasing issue with webGL (three.js, r64) when rendering into texture. I'm creating a topdown view of scene and than applying it as alpha cut texture on simple quad. It works fine with standard renderer.render() approach:

```
rtTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 1024, 1024, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat } );
renderer.render( scene, cameraRTT, rtTexture, true );
```

I've found some examples and this thread: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/568
After setuping the effect composer like this:

```
materialTopDown = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xcccccc}); 

var effectFXAA = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.ShaderExtras[ "fxaa" ] );
effectFXAA.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.set( 1 / SCREEN_WIDTH, 1 / SCREEN_HEIGHT );
effectFXAA.renderToScreen = true;

var renderScene = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, cameraRTT, materialTopDown, new THREE.Color(0x000000), 0 );

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, rtTexture );
composer.addPass( renderScene );
composer.addPass( effectFXAA );
```

and rendering:

```
composer.render();
```

When done like this I end up with all black rtTexture (when removing the effectFXAA path it's the same, so the problem is somewhere inside renderScene pass).

Can anyone maybe navigate me into correct direction?